# Saving an array in Tcl

Tags: arrays, loops, save, tcl, proc

I have a procedure in my code that is called in a loop. in this procedure, I want to store three variables in an array so at the end I can save the array in a text file. How can I do that?
example:
Main code:

```
for {set j 1} {$j<=[llength $Floor]} {incr j} {

myProc $matTag $j ........

}



proc myProc {....} {

 set Capacity($matTag) "$matTag $thetay $thetaP"

}
```

I have used this proc in my main code and at the end, if I have access to the array Capacity, I can save it. but this doesn't work within a proc.

Comment: You probably need to add `global Capacity` in the proc.

Comment: You'll also want to save the values into a list, not a string: `set Capacity($key) [list $val1 $val2 $val3]` -- if any of the values contains spaces, then with a string it will be impossible to extract the original values.

Answer (score 1):

All Tcl variables, *including arrays,* are scoped to their procedure (or lambda term, or method) by default. If you want something else, you have to *explicitly* ask for it. There are several ways to do this (`global`, `upvar`, `variable` and `namespace upvar`); the one that you probably need is `global`, which (efficiently) makes one or more variables into global variables:

```
proc myProc {....} {
    global Capacity

    set Capacity($matTag) "$matTag $thetay $thetaP"
}
```

Conventionally, the `global` is at the top of the procedure, as shown above. It doesn't have to be, but code tends to be a bit more readable if it is.